# Error while using Windows Subsystem for Linux to install Package?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 using the windows store and i started using them but I have a glitch. 
I'm unable to install any package and the terminal keeps returning these errors.

[Ubuntu Terminal error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDuBF.png)

It reads the package but provides an error stating

Error **Unable to locate the package[package-name]**

Some of the errors are

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ebtables
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
62 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/79.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 28484 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ebtables_2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Error: insufficient privileges to access the ebtables rulesets.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ebtables, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: old ebtables package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Error: insufficient privileges to access the ebtables rulesets.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ebtables, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ebtables_2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new ebtables package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ebtables_2.0.10.4-3.5ubuntu2.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@DESKTOP-SJPLLRG:~#
```

Is there any solution that would allow us to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and found the temporary solution in this github thread:  https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3274

Somewhere in the comments there is linked to a temporary fix: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1761#issuecomment-392575807